# Trying to install vsftpd via mac ports on snow leopard

Tags: macports

Using this guide: http://www.finiteloops.com/weblog/?p=79

I get this error:

```
500 OOPS: vsftpd: not configured for standalone, must be started from inetd
```

I am trying to turn on and off LISTEN in the config, but how to either link VSFTPD with INET or XINET or let it start in listen mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [man page](http://vsftpd.beasts.org/vsftpd_conf.html) for the config file for `vsftpd` should be of some help. If you set `listen=YES` in the config file, then `vsftpd` will be configured to run in standalone mode. It will then not be needed to be run from `inetd` or `xinetd`.

However, if you don't wish to run `vsftpd` in standalone mode, you will have to look at the man pages for `launchd` and launchctl`to figure out how to set up`vsftpd`to load via`launchd`. The`xinet`system was replaced with`launchd` on Snow Leopard.

Comment: <rant>This is really making me miss my Ubuntu setup.  I still can't figure out why people say Mac is great for developing, it is pretty, but Ubuntu is so straightforward with it's package management, Mac has all these hacks like homebrew and port to get around it's lack of integrated package management.</rant>

Comment: I didn't realize launchd was also a replacement for xinetd.  I used lingon and it shows this as the plist: http://pastebin.com/YwDygW1c
It is not disabled, but there is no entry for which port will trigger the call to this program.  Is this setup better on homebrew?  But I don't have xcode and have no desire to install xcode just for an ftp server.

Comment: I gave up on trying to get it working xinetd style and enabled LISTEN.  (I had to use lingon to see the name of the config file it was using, i had .config instead of .conf).  It is working now.  Thanks.

Comment: There's a new package manager called: [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/), you might want to give it a try. It's easier than MacPorts and Fink: [Homebrew: OS X’s Missing Package Manager](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/homebrew-os-xs-missing-package-manager/).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `listen=yes` in your config file?